# How to add label ID in Django Model Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using *Django ModelForm* for label. However, I don't know how to add label ID and I find nothings on Internet.

## UserForm

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'First Name', 'class': 'form-control input-md'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'class': 'form-control input-md'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'form-control input-md'}),
        }

        labels = {
            'first_name': "Họ",
            'last_name': "Tên",
            'email': "Email",
        }
```

## First name label

```
<label style="margin-left: -48px; margin-right: 48px;" class="col-md-4 control-label" for="">First Name</label>
```

Comment: Are you going to show the `id` which is stored in your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An `id` field is added automatically, but this behavior can be overridden. See [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).

So you need to add `id` to the `fields` of your *ModelForm* and then change it's label using the `labels` in the `Meta` class of the form.

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'First Name', 'class': 'form-control input-md'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'class': 'form-control input-md'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'form-control input-md'}),
        }

        labels = {
            'id': "ID",
            'first_name': "Họ",
            'last_name': "Tên",
            'email': "Email",
        }
```

Comment: In Form Django, I see id_for_label function, but in ModelForm Django I don't see that function. Explain for me, thanks